# Getting 500 backend error on /userlicenses

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to hit /userlicenses api of chromeWebstore api. But i get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "backendError",
        "message": "Backend Error"
      }
    ],
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Backend Error"
  }
}
```

This is only happening for all the new extensions that are created. 
Tried to contact google support but they are no help.
Please can anyone guide as to what can be done in this case?

Comment: Have you tried to handle it with exponential retry?

Comment: This api never works. I guess it is a problem from google's side. I checked for this error and it seems many people who are trying to get a paid extension version up on chrome webstore is experiencing this issue. If any body has got a workaround please let know. Thanks.

Comment: Same error, did you find the solution please?